# Transfer Interface value to new web tab page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have a code where user try to right click the A href then choose the "Open Link in new Tab" and display in the new tab the specific item they choose

I need to transfer the value of that specific a href what I have tried

create localStorage and store the value then access check if has a value the only problem is that the value what i need is object/interface value which the localStorage only can store is string

I have this code (Im using nextjs at reactjs)

```
 const handleClick = (e, deal: DealInterface, iixValues: EnterpriseDetailType) => {
    if (e.type === 'click') {
      console.log('Left click')
    } else if (e.type === 'contextmenu') {
      console.log('Right click')
      useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('hasNewPage', 'Yes')
        localStorage.setItem('dealData', JSON.stringify(deal))
        localStorage.setItem('iixValuesData', JSON.stringify(iixValues))
      }, [deal, iixValues])
    }
  }

  if (hasNewPage === 'No') {
    localStorage.setItem('hasNewPage', 'No')
    console.log('Not Transfer')
    localStorage.removeItem('iixValuesData')
  } else if (hasNewPage === 'Yes') {
    const [name, setName] = useState(() => {
      // getting stored value
      const saved = localStorage.getItem('dealData')
      const initialValue = JSON.parse(saved)
      return initialValue || ''
    })
    console.log(`Value ${name}`)
    localStorage.removeItem('hasNewPage')
  }
```

Comment: React hooks, like `useEffect` and `useState`, cannot be used conditionally or inside regular functions.